Strange stripes on Google Maps in the region of the October Revolution Island
On 2024-04-16 one can see strange stripes located roughly at 79.86317, 94.64563 in the region of the October Revolution Island.
What could be the source of these stripes in an end product?
I mean, they should have been removed by any processing step...


These are present also on Bing maps, but in much lesser measure: https://www.bing.com/maps/?cp=79.551193%7E94.881774&lvl=8.4&style=h. Seems their image processing is better.

Landsat-7 SLC-Off data perhaps. https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-landsat-7-etm-slc-data
